# How to achieve click effect on ShapeableImageView, min api 21 without nesting view

Tags: android, android-layout, material-components-android, material-components

Is there a better way to achieve click effect on [ShapeableImageView](http://lib/java/com/google/android/material/imageview/ShapeableImageView.java) with recent release of Material components [v1.2.0](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/releases/tag/1.2.0)

I do not want to use foreground property as it is available after api level 23 and my current min  sdk level is 21.
eg `android:foreground="?selectableItemBackground"`

The only solution currently that I have is to nest a view on top of ImageView, but this seems to be bad solution as just to get a click I have to add a nested view on top of it.

Also I would consider to do it purely using XML and no coding as I have many layouts with ImageView grids.

There are similar questions on SO already asked for `ImageView` and `AppCompatImageView` but those are either legacy solutions, target api level 23 using foreground or third party lib.

Below is my layout which will be used inside a `RecyclerView` as a grid item

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="..."
    xmlns:app="..."
    xmlns:tools="..."
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <com.google.android.material.imageview.ShapeableImageView
        android:id="@+id/art"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="1:1"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:shapeAppearanceOverlay="@style/ShapeAppearanceOverlay.App.CornerSize50Percent"
        tools:src="@tools:sample/avatars" />

    <com.google.android.material.imageview.ShapeableImageView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:background="@drawable/ripple_effect"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:focusable="true"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/art"
        app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="1:1"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/art"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/art"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/art"
        app:shapeAppearanceOverlay="@style/ShapeAppearanceOverlay.App.CornerSize50Percent" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Below is the style to make ImageView into full circle

```
<!-- CornerSize50Percent -->
<style name="ShapeAppearanceOverlay.App.CornerSize50Percent" parent="">
    <item name="cornerSize">50%</item>
</style>
```

Below is the ripple effect drawable

```
<!-- ripple_effect -->
<ripple xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:color="#DEFFFFFF">
    <item
        android:id="@android:id/mask"
        android:drawable="@android:color/white" />
</ripple>
```

Link to issue on [github](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/issues/1782)